# Array Semi-Flattening

Tags: ruby, arrays, arguments, apply

Want to convert this:

```
[["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]]
```

to this:

```
["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"]
```

to be passed into Array.product(), and the first array can contain an unknown number of other arrays. for example, the array given may also be

```
[["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"]]
```

And ultimately, I need to pass the argument as:

```
otherArray.product(["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"])
```

Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
otherArray.product(*[["1", "2", "3"], ["4", "5", "6"], ["7", "8", "9"]]);
```

> * is used in argument list to unpack array contents to arguments (like
>   here) or to pack arguments into an array,like in "def mymethod(*args)"

Reference: http://www.justskins.com/forums/apply-method-to-array-17387.html

Comment: Quite a useful operator in Python as well.

Answer (score 1):

I think what would work for you is using Ruby's Array expansion:

```
a=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b=[1,2,3].product([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
c=[1,2,3].product(*a)
b == c #This should be true
```

Basically putting the asterisk (*) in front of the variable will expand all elements in the array into a list of arguments, which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of code aside, the rest of it seems to be solved by using the 0 index:

```
arr[0]
```

Comment: I don't follow, that would only return the first array from the others, and won't dynamically include all arrays